# How to scrape data from css?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape some data from a web page and some url s. But some data that required to be scraped are in the style sheet. and not included in the html.  How can I extract that data?

html:

```
<div class="bgimage"></div>
```

css:

```
.bgimage {
    background-image: url(/bg/image/site/bg.png);
}
```

when I inspect the page, I could see that the image url i want to scrape was under the styles tab.  How can I scrape such data? Is it possible?

Comment: all css are either styles embedded with a `<style>` tag or files linked with `<link rel="stylesheet" ...`. beautifulsoup will get you those. but you'll have then to parse css and this can be tricky. some libraries exist for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the links of the stylesheets and then scrape them.

```
css_files = []

for css in soup.find_all("link"):
    if css.attrs.get("href"):
        # if the link tag has the 'href' attribute
        css_url = urljoin(baseurl, css.attrs.get("href"))
        css_files.append(css_url)
```